# How to install OpenShift Origin on Windows 7?

Tags: linux, vmware, redhat, openshift-origin

I am wanting to install OpenShift Origin on my PC running Windows 7.

I am completely new to Linux environments and terminology but wanted to 'look around' the OpenShift product with the hope that I can become familiar with its offerings and features.

So I have started here:

https://www.openshift.com/products/origin

Where the instructions are:

"The easiest way to run OpenShift Origin locally is to download an image suitable for running on a VM. The image will work on KVM , VirtualBox or VMWare .  You can also spin up a VirtualBox instance using Vagrant or build your own machine using Puppet".

I have downloaded `openshift-origin.latest.tgz` and I am assuming the next step is to download and install a 'VM' (something I also have never used)?

I have heard the name VMWare before but when I visit the site there seem to be 15+ different products and I'm not sure which one is required for the above task.

So, is it possible for someone to provide a `<ul>` of steps required to install and run OpenShift Origin on Windows 7?

A google search for `how to install openshift origin on windows 7?` does not seem to return any immediately obvious results (the first result links to an article that starts with `[obsolete]`).

There is a video called 'open shift origin setup' here:

http://youtu.be/rzW3N_C5sIE

But it starts with a file called 'openshift_origin.iso' and not the 'openshift-origin.latest.tgz' that I have downloaded and then it gets into some terminal coding that is completely foreign to me.

Any pointers appreciated.

**Edit:**

In addition to accepted answer below, as virtual machines may be a bit ominous to newbies here are some screenshots which show the installation of VirtualBox, it was really pretty easy.

For Windows 7, I downloaded `VirtualBox 4.2.16 for Windows hosts  x86/amd64` from:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

and then ran the installer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you will see a few of these type of screens, just click 'Install'.

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately then when running OpenShift, as per instructions in accepted answer, I got this message:

[image]

And I haven't been able to find a workaround to this yet.

But this error shouldn't occur for those who have hardware acceleration enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## VirtualBox

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is freely available.

- Open VirtualBox from the Start Menu - this opens the VirtualBox Manager.
- Open the menu **File** > **Import Appliance** or press CTRL+I.
- Click **Open Appliance...**
- Browse to the folder you downloaded OpenShift Origin to.
- Select the `.ovf` file.
- Press **Next**.
- Press **Import**.

It'll import the file for a while (roughly 2 minutes on my computer) and show up as a Virtual Machine afterwards. You can just click **Start** and it'll boot up.

## VMWare

[VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/de/products/desktop_virtualization/player/overview.html) is free for personal non-commercial use while most other VMWare products are not.

I haven't personally tried this route, but it seems easy enough to just open the `.vmx` file directly.

Comment: I followed steps for 'VirtualBox' scenario.  After pressing 'Start' I received error: `VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system.  Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot`.  My environment is Win 7 Home Premium, 64-bit OS.  I googled error and came across solution: 'Start VirtualBox, select the virtual machine where you want to run your 64-Bit OS and go into the settings of this VM. Look for "Settings -> System -> Acceleration" and make sure that "Enable VT-x/AMD-V" is activated'.  However 'Acceleration' tab is not clickable.

Comment: Further specs:  Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q8200 @ 2.33GHz 2.34 GHz, Installed Memory (RAM):  4.00GB

Comment: Motherboard:  Asus P5Q3 Deluxe

Comment: Your CPU lacks VT-x, which is Intel's virtualization support implemented in Hardware. All 64-bit images, including OpenShift, require VT-x to work on VirtualBox (as you have noticed). [The VMWare requirements point out likewise](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003945) - though checking the offered [compability tool](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ==) might be more helpful. I am not aware if or how you'd get any OpenShift server to run inside a 32-bit VM, the default images won't work.

Comment: In Win8.1 this error is caused by installing Microsoft's virtualisation technology through add/remove windows features installer

Answer (score 0):

Your choices of software to run the ISO (VM image with Fedora) on Windows is VirtualBox or VMWware Workstation.  Here's an interesting article that compares the 2:
http://www.infoworld.com/d/virtualization/review-vmware-workstation-9-vs-virtualbox-42-203277

Comment: Where is the ISO file? I have clicked the 'Download' link at https://www.openshift.com/products/origin and it downloads `openshift-origin.latest.tgz` (729MB), when i unzip that directory i cannot see any ISO file.  It contains 5 files `openshift-origin.ks`, `openshift-origin.ovf`, `openshift-origin.vmx`, `openshift-origin.xml`, `openshift-origin-sda.vmdk`.

Answer (score 0):

2 unrelated things here...

First, if you do not have a hardware virtualization enabled 64 bit processor (listed as VT-X on Intel chips, and AMD-V on AMD processors), then you cannot host an OpenShift Origin VM, which itself spawns VMs, and thus not only needs the virtualization enabled processor, but needs its VirtualBox VM enabled for virtualization (a checkbox under System/Acceleration in the settings for the VM).

Second, OpenShift Origin relies on multicast DNS, which is not supported on Windows 7, so it won't work.

If you can install Fedora 20 Alpha (I expect Fedora 19 will work, but I haven;t tried it) onto metal, then install VirtualBox and the nss-mdns RPM, that should work.

Been there, done that, got the headache.